# loop through json with groovy

Tags: json, groovy, jenkins-groovy

I need to access the list in "memberNames".
I save the jsonfile in the variable jsonString.

```
{
  "name" : "maven_prueba",
  "format" : "maven2",
  "url" : "http://lnexusapp01:8081/repository/maven_prueba",
  "online" : true,
  "storage" : {
    "blobStoreName" : "default",
    "strictContentTypeValidation" : true
  },
  "group" : {
    "memberNames" : [ "borrarMaven", "aaaaas", "borrardamian1" ]
  },
  "type" : "group"
}
```

```
def jsonObj = readJSON text: jsonString
echo jsonObj.group //return null
echo jsonObj.name
```

Thanks for the help!!!!

Comment: your code is correct. something wring with content of jsonString variable.

Comment: I print on screen before moving forward and it brings all the content
```
echo jsonString
```
I need to save the values in an array

Answer (score 1):

your code is fine

```
def jsonString = '''{
  "name" : "maven_prueba",
  "format" : "maven2",
  "url" : "http://lnexusapp01:8081/repository/maven_prueba",
  "online" : true,
  "storage" : {
    "blobStoreName" : "default",
    "strictContentTypeValidation" : true
  },
  "group" : {
    "memberNames" : [ "borrarMaven", "aaaaas", "borrardamian1" ]
  },
  "type" : "group"
}'''

def jsonObj = readJSON text: jsonString

echo jsonObj.group.memberNames //prints array
```